# MySQL: An error occurred during the signature verification

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, mysql, repository

Through VirtualBox, even in different machines, I have 2 Ubuntu Server 20.04 instances running with the following info:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Both have MySQL installed with the same instructions that I used since months ago. Suddenly just for one of them when I do `sudo apt update` appears the following:

```
Get:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease [12.9 kB]
Hit:3 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:4 https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu focal Release
Get:6 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Err:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
Get:9 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:10 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:7 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 349 kB in 3s (133 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Questions**

- Why did do happen this?
- How to solve it?

Comment: It could be the answer of question 2, but what about the 1?

Comment: It's because you've missing GPG keys.

Comment: But why happened that?, in the same instance many times MySQL was updated without any problem with `sudo apt update` and later of course with `sudo apt upgrade`. Why suddenly the `GPG keys` are missing?

Comment: Well, that's because you did something strange with your system... How can I or anyone tell?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You will want to import the missing GPG keys for the repository like this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt update
```

You should be good

Comment: This was useful for building old 1.10.x airflow containers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The latest key can be found in here https://itsfoss.community/t/how-to-fix-apt-update-after-to-upgrade-the-mysql-list-file/11546/2

Comment: Behind a firewall, `hkp://` and port `:80` are needed. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C` The key id in this comment is from the year 2024. More info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399027/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-server-indicated-a-failure/399091#399091

Comment: Correction: not a firewall issue. Port 11371 works also, even if it is closed by ufw. Without port number and hkp protocol, this does not work. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371 --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C`. More info in the link in my other comment.