# How to fix apt update after to upgrade the mysql.list file?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, mysql

After to did do an upgrade through VirtualBox for Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 to 22.04 - `focal` to `jammy` - at the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory exists the `mysql.list` file.

According with a research was indicated to open that file and change from `local` to `jammy`. Therefore I have now

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
manueljordan@mac2013-vb143:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

Now when is executed the `sudo apt update` command happens the following:

```
sudo apt update
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease [20.2 kB]
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                        
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease    
Hit:5 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
Hit:7 http://pe.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 20.2 kB in 2s (11.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
16 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As you can see there are many errors

How to fix apt update after to upgrade the mysql.list file?

Comment: It's REALLY annoying that questions like this keep getting closed. They don't have answers that work consistently, and claiming they do is akin to religious faith... The only way I was able to get this working was by (re)installing the apt setup package from the Oracle site - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: The answer(s) worked in peace ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Has been answered [previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389928/mysql-an-error-occurred-during-the-signature-verification). The only thing you need to change is the reported public key.

The following command was the solution there:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C
```

Comment: And the referred link was posted by myself time ago :) - yes the following command was the solution `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C`

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C` did not help in my case, i also needed to update /etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg with `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C && rm /etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg && gpg  --output /etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg --export B7B3B788A8D3785C` because i was still getting the same errors as in the original post

Comment: @bigbear3001 interesting your situation ...

Comment: @bigbear3001, I have the same situation, but even replacing this file doesn't fix it. been trying with apt-key export & gpg dearmour, but nothing so far...

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem do you have a key specified in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/... file? i think i needed to replace the file mentioned in `deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg ...` because adding it to the general keyring does not help if the sources list file specifies a special key file.

Comment: Thanks @bigbear3001! That was it. I installed mysql via "mysql-apt-config", and this installs a key under `/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg`. So moving the key I made under `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.gpg` to that location fixed the "NO_PUBKEY" error.

Comment: Another alternative `apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C` or `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C && gpg --export B7B3B788A8D3785C > /etc/apt/keyrings/mysql.gpg`

Comment: `hkp://` and port `:80` are needed. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B7B3B788A8D3785C` More info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399027/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-server-indicated-a-failure/399091#399091