# MySQL Installation issues on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mysql, repository, gnupg, mysql-workbench

Trying to install MySQL and Workbench on Ubuntu 22.04, issues with GPG key. When running update to see if my changes have had effect I persistently get:

```
: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy 
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B7B3B788A8D3785C
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have removed and reinstalled the public key to the APT keyring, fetched the key directly from keyserver, deleted and reinstalled the repository.
Any takers? Could really use some advice...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1497141/374062

Comment: The public key wasn't found, so you might have to add the key accordingly. If that's what you tried update your question to include that step and we'll troubleshoot further

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work:

Get rid of MySQL, Directories, Configuration files, Repositories, GPG Keys:
sudo apt purge mysql-server
mysql-client
mysql-common
mysql-server-core-*
mysql-client-core-*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

Find replace MySQL.GPG key id,
sudo apt-key list
sudo apt-key del 
sudo apt update

Get .Debs from MySQL - Repositories, MySQL Server, Workbench; Download.

Extract and install

If you get unmet dependencies check version

Remove the existing version of mysql-community-client-plugins:
sudo apt remove mysql-community-client-plugins

Install the required version of mysql-community-client-plugins:
sudo apt install mysql-community-client-plugins=8.0.36-1ubuntu22.04

Retry installing MySQL Workbench:
sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community-dbgsym_8.0.36-1ubuntu22.04_amd64.deb

;)